# Transações concorrentes no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, concorrência

Estou trabalhando em um sistema que preciso sortear vários dados(cupons) de uma tabela e retornar para o usuário, mas não posso correr o risco de entregar o mesmo cupom para o outro usuário.

Pensei em usar o [GET_LOCK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) do MySQL para bloquear a tabela temporariamente enquanto o sorteio é feito, mas ele não segura a conexão HTTP e a conexão se perde tendo que fazer a chamada novamente.

Existe alguma forma correta ou apenas melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: Eu escrevi uma [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2072/223) em Janeiro que apesar de não ser para o teu caso em particular penso que será a solução para o teu problema. A resposta faz referência ao [MySQL LOCK TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html). Dá uma vista de olhos, alguma informação avisa.

Comment: @Zuul darei uma lida na sua resposta mais a fundo, mas pelo que vi é bem provável que isto me ajude muito.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Concordo com o @mlemos, nunca se deve trabalhar com LOCK TABLES em aplicações, exceto para situações muitos especificas.

Para situações assim, é preciso conhecer um pouco o esquema de transação do banco.
MySQL não é meu "forte", mas o conceito para banco de dados OLTP é universal.

No caso do MySQL, que com todo respeito, mas é uma "colcha de retalhos", esta resposta vai ser valida apena se você estiver usando o engine **innoDB**.

Aqui o controle de lock será através de SQL, sob o registro na tabela que você irá usar para controlar que "Este cupom já foi sorteado".

**Primeiro**, você tem que se preocupar com o SET ISOLATION, ele irá definir como sua sessão deverá se comportar durante o acesso a um dado.
Para este caso eu recomendaria o : `set session transaction isolation level read committed;`
Para maiores informações de uma lida no manual do [MySQL aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html).
Este *isolation level* irá garantir que você só irá ler dados que estão *comitados*/confirmados no banco.

**Segundo**, definir um *time-out* que sua transação irá aguardar por um lock.
Isto serve para que o update , caso concorra com outro, tenha um tempo limite para aguardar a liberação do registro.
No MySQL isso é feito com o comando `set session innodb_lock_wait_timeout=10`
Aqui configurei para 10 segundos, o que considero mais que suficiente.
Caso não seja suficiente, você pode aumentar este tempo e/ou deverá preparar sua aplicação para tratar a exceção `ERROR HY000: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`
Para maiores informações de uma lida no manual do [MySQL aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-other-changes-innodb_lock_wait_timeout.html)

**Terceiro**, desativar o *autocommit* para que você possa ter maior controle sobre a transação, de quando ele começa e quando ela deve terminar. 
Para isso usar o `SET autocommit = 0`

**Quarto**, iniciar uma transação com `start transaction` ou `begin work`.
Tanto faz qual dos dois comandos, pois são sinonimos.
Mas o importante aqui, é ter em mente que tudo que você alterar no banco de dados, ficara com um lock ativo até que a transação seja finalizada!

**Quinto**, realizar o update que irá salvar a informação de que o cupon X foi sorteado.
Esta é a parte crucial da lógica e como você não postou nenhum exemplo de tabela, estrutura, SQL que utilizou vou postar algo da minha imaginação mesmo.

```
update cupons set sorteado=134 where sorteado is null and cupom_id = 4444 ;
```

Explicando:

- A coluna sorteado é o flag que diz se o cupom já foi sorteado. 
  seu conteúdo é o numero do sorteio (para que você possa relacionar o sorteio do dia/hora X com o cupom Y)
- O cupom_id é o campo chave do cupom, no caso o 4444 seria o tal do cupom sorteado. 
  Naturalmente você deve ter a sua logica para isso...
- O `where sorteado is null` uma das pernas no "pulo do gato".
  Ele irá minimizar a chance de pegar um cupom que está sendo sorteado exatamente no mesmo momento, porém ainda assim isso pode ocorrer, se ocorrer, o tratamento de LOCK do SQL irá entrar em ação e evitar de atualizar este cupom porque a sua sessão irá "travar" e aguardar a outra transação finalizar (devido o timeout configurado), quando a outra transação finalizar, esta volta a ativa e deverá identificar que a coluna sorteado foi preenchido, ou seja, "is not null" e não irá atualizar nada, zero registros.

***Então o "pulo do gato" está no "is null" na coluna sorteado + o controle de transação.***

**Sexto** , verificar quantas linhas foram atualizadas no update acima, se for 1, quer dizer que tudo deu certo... caso contrário, sortear outro cupom...
Para isso utilize a função row_count().
Para maiores informações de uma lida no manual do [MySQL aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count).

**Setimo**, finalizar a transação com um `commit` ou `rollback`, conforme a sua logica.

---

Para ilustrar uma sequencia de comandos onde fiz a mesma coisa em uma sessão paralela..

```
mysql> use test
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> create table cupons (cupom_id integer, sorteado integer);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql>
mysql> insert into cupons (cupom_id) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> set session transaction isolation level read committed;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set session innodb_lock_wait_timeout=60;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET autocommit = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> begin work;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

-- aqui em outra sessão executei o mesmo update com os mesmos 
-- parametros de sessao exemplificado aqui..
-- depois de executar o update aqui, na outra sessão comitei a transação.
-- observe o tempo do update abaixo e a qtde de linhas atualizadas.
mysql> update cupons set sorteado=134 where sorteado is null and cupom_id = 4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (11.14 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 4):

Você não deve travar tabelas com LOCK TABLES em aplicações normais. Deve antes usar transações com o nível de isolamento correto para impedir que acessos simultâneos alterem os mesmos registros.

Veja aqui esta outra resposta para [garantir o accesso integro a tabela com transações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2069/dar-um-select-antes-de-um-insert-e-uma-forma-segura-de-nao-ter-registros-dup/2975#2975).